# Vite.Js, ¿Cómo crear una carpeta específicamente para las imágenes(jpg, png, svg)?

Tags: configuración, vite

estoy trabajando con Vite.js, estoy buscando la manera de configurar vitejs para que cuando ejecute **npm run build** y me cree la carpeta dist/build adentro de esa misma carpeta me cree otra carpeta donde irán todas las imágenes(jpg, png, svg, etc), quiero que cree algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me e dedicado a buscar la manera pero no consigo/entiendo la manera de como hacerlo

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. En referencia a tu pregunta: lo que querés decir es que querés una carpeta exclusiva para imágenes, _fuera de `assets`_?

Comment: Encontraste la solucion para este problema... estoy igualmente pegado no me agrega mis imagenes locales al build saludos

Comment: En el archivo de raiz crea una carpeta public / assets dentro tus img.. luego corre npm run build